# Python code of Runge-Kutta (GLONASS Ephemeris)

Tags: python, gps, satellite, runge-kutta

I'm looking for an explanation on how to extrapolate GLONASS satellites by using the Runge-Kutta 4 technique. My problem is basically on how to jump from the K1 to K2 step and beyond, by applying inputs to a function. I can't figure out exactly, what the function should be. Here is my code:

```
def satellite_acceleration(self, radius):
    mu_hat = cs.GM / (radius**2)
    x_a_hat = self.sv_pos_X / radius
    y_a_hat = self.sv_pos_Y / radius
    z_a_hat = self.sv_pos_Z / radius
    rho_hat = cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS / radius

    modified_acc_xa = (-mu_hat*x_a_hat) + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * mu_hat * x_a_hat * (rho_hat**2) * (1 - (5*(z_a_hat**2)))) + self.sv_acc_X_LS + ((cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2) * self.sv_pos_X) + (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * self.sv_vel_Y)
    modified_acc_ya = (-mu_hat*y_a_hat) + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * mu_hat * y_a_hat * (rho_hat**2) * (1 - (5*(z_a_hat**2)))) + self.sv_acc_Y_LS + ((cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2) * self.sv_pos_Y) - (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * self.sv_vel_X)
    modified_acc_za = (-mu_hat*z_a_hat) + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * mu_hat * z_a_hat * (rho_hat**2) * (3 - (5*(z_a_hat**2)))) + self.sv_acc_Z_LS 

    X_dot_arrow = [self.sv_vel_X, self.sv_vel_Y, self.sv_vel_Z, modified_acc_xa, modified_acc_ya, modified_acc_za]  

    return X_dot_arrow


def runge_kutta_4(self, X_dot_arrow):
    X_arrow = [self.sv_pos_X, self.sv_pos_Y, self.sv_pos_Z, self.sv_vel_X, self.sv_vel_Y, self.sv_vel_Z]

    h = 30      #Seconds (to change dependent on epoch interval)
    t = 0       #Iterator
    w = xxx     #TBC

    for i in range(total_time):
        k_1 = h * X_dot_arrow
        #k_1 = h * self.function(t, w)
        k_2 = h * self.function(t + (h/2), w + (k_1 / 2))
        k_3 = h * self.function(t + (h/2), w + (k_2 / 2))
        k_4 = h * self.function(t + h, w + k_3)
        w = w + ((k_1 + (2*k_2) + (2*k_3) + k_4) / 6)
        t = t + h                

def function(self, t, w):
    pass
```

There's a fair bit of literature out there on how to extrapolate for GPS satellites, but unfortunately GLONASS appears to be more limited. All feedback welcome.

Comment: ...what exactly is your question?

Comment: My apologies for the ambiguity. The problem I face is more mathematical than coding itself. The Runge-Kutta 4 (RK4) process is clear, but how to apply this to victory, specifically the "X_arrow" and "X_dot_arrow" is not clear. In order to propagate the GLONASS satellites, iterative steps are calculated using RK4. In the code snipped I above, it is not clear to apply RK4 for K2 (k_2) and onwards. I guess this question would be better targeted to the geodesy and/or mathematics community as opposed to python coder. Thanks.

Comment: The issue I'm facing with this relates to the translation of the k1, k2 steps etc from interpolating the GLONASS satellites. A link to the instruction is given here:[http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/GLONASS_Satellite_Coordinates_Computation] and the method how to apply the time intervals in order to reach the k2 is not clear.

Comment: Then I'm not sure you're in the right way place, you don't seem to have a concrete coding issue.

Comment: Yes could be. My problem appears now to be more mathematical (how to compute satellite positions, at every 30 seconds, for 15 minutes before/after a central point).